# Boost shared_from_this and destructor

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, object-lifetime, weak-ptr

I found that it is not allowed to call shared_from_this in the destructor from a class:

https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/147

> This behavior is by design. Since the destructor will destroy the object, it is not safe to create a shared_ptr to it as it will become dangling once the destructor ends.

I understand the argument, but what if I need a "shared_from_this" pointer for cleaning up references ( not for sharing owner ship).

Here is an example where I'm not using shared_ptr:

```
class A{
public:
    A( Manager * m ) : m_(m) {
        m_->add(this);
    }

    ~A() {
        m_->remove(this);
    }

private:
    Manager * m_;
};
```

Here I have tried to translate it into shared pointers. But I can not find a good way to finish the destructor:

```
class A : public boost::enable_shared_from_this< A > {
public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr< A > Ptr;

    static Ptr create( Manager * m ) {
        Ptr p( new A(m));
        p->init();
        return p;
    }

    ~A() {
        // NON-WORKING
        // m_->remove( shared_from_this() );
    }

private:
    A( Manager * m ) : m_(m) { }

    void init() {
        m_->add(shared_from_this());
    }

    Manager * m_;
};
```

How can I implement the destructor in the example above?

Comment: I want to create new tags: misuse-of-weak-ptr misunderstanding-of-enabled-shared-from-this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your Manager has a `shared_ptr` to your object, then it owns it.
Thus your object shall not be destructed, as the Manager still have a reference to it.

You may pass a weak pointer to the Manager, but then it's the work of the manager to check that the pointer is still valid, and delete it if not.

Your question is interesting, but your case is caused by a misconception. As long as an object own a reference to your object, it's the aim of shared_ptr that it will not be destructed. For the destructor to be called, you should have manually called delete on the pointer, which is a bad behavior when working with shared_ptr.

Simple define who really own the object, and give them the shared_ptr. If a part of code occasionally need your object - if it exists - then give it a weak_ptr.

Answer (score 3):

If the Manager instance has a shared_ptr to your class, your class will never be destroyed until that shared_ptr is gone. I assume, therefore, that Manager is actually storing a weak_ptr to your instance, in which case Manager's API should probably accept a weak_ptr which you should be able to get in the destructor. If you can't, just make one in your constructor and store it for later.

Comment: By design the weak_ptr serves to let the object be destroyed. So it is to the object owning the weak_ptr to check its validity.
But good solution anyway.

Comment: Just trying to present some options for what you pointed out as being a bit of a misconceived problem, in that we shouldn't be in the situation of unregistering ourselves in our destructor from something which holds a shared_ptr to us.

Comment: Hello. "a weak_ptr which you should be able to get in the destructor" --- can you please explain, how can I get weak_ptr in destructor? `enable_shared_from_this` contains only `shared_from_this`, not `weak_from_this`...

Comment: @hate-engine There's finally support for `weak_from_this` in C++17.

Comment: @rwols How would you use that?

Comment: a use case would be a cache map removing their cached weak pointers upon destruction of the obj. The obj can now trigger a signal with its weak_from_this() arg to let other objs know that it is about to be gone.

Answer (score 2):

> Here I have tried to translate it into shared pointers.

Don't.

Your first class is fine (except that it is an implicitly declared copy constructor and copy assignment - unrelated with the use of raw pointers).

Why bother with smart pointers? because it's fashionable?

`weak_ptr` is often misunderstood as a pointer-like class (it is not, it is a weak reference thing).

`weak_ptr` is rarely appropriate. (Even with Boost documentation spreads confusion about when `weak_ptr` is appropriate.)

`enable_shared_from_this` is even easier to misunderstand.