# How to handle need for valid std::shared_ptr in destructor of object?

Tags: c++

I have an object that is owned by a shared_ptr and sends out various events all of which include a shared_ptr to the object with them. The object has a shutdown state that is of interest to other parts of the system and uses an event to inform about entering that state. The object must inform about going into a shutdown state before it disappears so other things can know it won't be doing anything anymore. The obvious and not valid solution to making sure the shutdown event always goes out is to send the event from the object destructor but [`shared_from_this()` can't be used in any kind of sane way from inside the destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28338978/stdenable-shared-from-this-is-it-allowed-to-call-shared-from-this-in-destru).

Given the limitations of `shared_from_this()` and a `shared_ptr` lifetime and the requirements what options are available? Currently the destructor enforces that the object is already in the shutdown state which is not optimal because the only two options I can think of are to throw an exception, which is highly discouraged in a destructor, or call `abort()` which is currently what happens. This object is a part of a library and calling `abort()` is rather rude even if the documentation clearly says the object has to be shutdown prior to destruction. Unfortunately it's rather easy to wind up in a situation where the object goes out of scope prior to calling the shutdown method and I'd rather my library not be rude.

I tried calling the `shared_ptr` constructor and passing in a custom deleter function but `shared_ptr` is invoking the deleter after `shared_from_this()` will throw an exception which makes sense given the reference count and ownership issue that was explained in the previous link. One other thought I had was using a small wrapper class that itself holds a `shared_ptr` to the object and handing that out also owned by a shared_ptr as the API instead of handing out a `shared_ptr` to the object itself. The wrapper destructor would handle shutting down the object which would leave the object's `shared_ptr` intact but this seems like a bad idea because:

1. The events will have a `shared_ptr<Object>` instead of `shared_ptr<Wrapper>` which is inconsistent.
2. Something could conceivably make a copy of `shared_ptr<Object>` outside the view of `shared_ptr<Wrapper>`.

Another thought I had is to have object events include either a raw pointer or reference to the object instead of a `shared_ptr` but events could be queued and consumed in other threads which becomes highly problematic. This approach is also inconsistent like using a wrapper class would be. The shutdown event could also be specifically documented to possibly hold a `nullptr` and be invalid or could be a `weak_ptr` instead of `shared_ptr` but a `weak_ptr` won't ensure the object stays alive for the lifetime of an event which is a guarantee I'd like to offer. As well supplying a `nullptr` in the `shared_ptr` means the shutdown event consumer would need a handler that itself knows which object did the sending or the most useful information they are guranteed to receive is "an object shutdown" instead of "this specific object shutdown" which isn't really that useful.

The related functions of `use_count()` and `unique()` in `std::shared_ptr` are dead ends because I'm using C++20 so [`unique()` is gone](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/unique) and `use_count()` has [this warning](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/use_count):

> In multithreaded environment, the value returned by `use_count` is approximate (typical implementations use a memory_order_relaxed load).

Is making a contract that the object must always be shutdown prior to destruction and calling `abort()` the best I can do?

Comment: IMO the fundamental problem is can event handler extend the lifetime of the object or not? If yes, then you can't use a destructor and need a separate shutdown function, and if not, you can't meaningfully pass a `shared_ptr`. Perhaps if it can't extend the lifetime, you could write a wrapper for `weak_ptr` that can't be converted to `shared_ptr`, and has `std::optional`-like [`.and_then()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/and_then). Then the client can use the object in the handler, and would get a nice error message (from the `weak_ptr` wrapper) after the handler returns.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ah the weak_ptr wrapper is an interesting idea. Thank you. It also occured to me that instead of calling abort() in the destructor I can log a warning which is less rude. There is a separate shutdown method this is really just about the best way to handle the situation where it wasn't called prior to destruction.

Comment: If you're going to print a warning, I'd also add an `assert()` (possibly using a customizable macro). Probably no one reads the logs. :P

Comment: The solution here is that your uberobject is a fake, a phony, and a fraud. It is not. It's just a fake shell with its own shared_ptr to the real uberobject, and methods that forward to the real one. It's destructor then grabs the shared_ptr, perhaps creates a substitute imposter, and then does what it needs to do.

Comment: Just an idea. Have a custom deleter function that calls your shutdown function. Inside shutdown, you can do one of the two things: `delete this`, **or** resurrect the object by creating another shared_ptr to it (not with enable_shared_from_this, it's not needed; just normally with `std::shared_ptr<MyClass> resurrected = this;`. You can do that because you know the old reference count is zero, so the old shared_ptr will not interfere with the new one.) Send the reports with the new shared pointer and return (the shutdown has failed, but there will be another one).

Comment: `weak_ptr` has a `lock` function that extends lifetime  of underlying `shared_ptr` to required amount if the underlying is valid at call site: `if (shared_ptr shrd = weak.lock()) use(shrd);`  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/lock

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI That worked like a treat! Thank you.